# Highlight the "How to Ask" section when a new user posts a question for the first time

Tags: feature-request

Stack Overflow has a high number of new users registering per day. With the excitement or impatience to ask the first question, they often oversee the 'How to Ask', 'Be Specific' and 'How to Format' sections.

Many novice users make mistakes like adding signatures at the end of a question and not properly formatting their questions. Therefor my suggestion is that it would be better if these sections were highlighted by using bulging and minimizing borders or shining border, etc.

Comment: Any comments for downvote?

Comment: (not the one who downvoted) I think you'd have more luck making the user take a quick quiz before they're allowed to submit a question.

Comment: Thats another superb thing to do. +1 for that.

Comment: I *did* downvote - 1. "This is just a suggestion/Thank You" is just as much a signature (which you point out is a mistake) as any other, 2. New users already get an in-your-face message to ask good questions, 3. This has been asked many times before, 4. Downvotes on Meta are different to downvotes on SO.

Answer (score 6):

I know you think that would be a speed bump that could slow down the incoming flow of junk, but it wouldn't be. Someone in a hurry to take a crap in a question box in hopes of getting answers isn't going to stop and look around first, much less take time to read.

The people that *would* follow the link would generally not need it, as they've probably already taken some time to look around, browsed the FAQ and gained a basic understanding of how the system works.

I'm not looking at hard data while writing this, I'm just reflecting on the last year of being a moderator. New users are presented with enough helpful hints to have a good experience, and thankfully a lot of people follow them. They need a little guidance early on, but they generally get up to speed quickly.

Those that ignore what we already have in place won't be helped by adding more, at least in my opinion.